# how to divide test server and service server using only one source code in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, tomcat, server

### how to divide server for test and service using one source

I'm developing APIs.
I wanna make test server for test DB, and make an other service server for real DB. using one source

I'm developing APIs with spring boots that have embedded tomcat.

i want servers start together and one server uses one only one DB, test or real

i don't want make two source.
can i make divided two servers only one source?
it is possible what to do? do i make any config? please share your idea

Comment: do you want both at the same time or else one at a time will work for you ?

Comment: What did you mean "using one resource"? Because there will be two different configurations for testing DB and real DB. Or did you mean that configure these 2 data sources in one properties?

Comment: how do you connect and configure your databse soirce?

Comment: i want both at the same time and  i mean configure 2 data sources in one properties so I wanna make source code to run for two different server.